# Convert result of File.ReadAllBytes as File object without actually writing it

Tags: c#, file, bytestream

One Module reads some files using

```
File.ReadAllBytes("path")
```

and stores the result in a database table.

Later I take the result from the table and normaly use

```
File.WriteAllBytes("outputPath", binary.Data)
```

to write the file back.

Now I have to change the content of the file. Of course I can write the file to a temp folder, read it back in as a File object, change it, write it back to the destination folder.
But is there a smarter way to do that? Create the File object directly out of the binary data?

Comment: Use MemoryStream.

Comment: The Memory Stream gives me back a string, but I have a CSV file with many lines and need to access file.ReadAllLines().

Comment: other than that you simply can come up with a data structure similar to CSV, and feed that populated data structure to a composer function.

Comment: What do you mean “as File object” ?

Comment: I want to use the File.ReadAllLines Method. Or any other method which allows me to convert the binary data of a csv into a list of the single lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution. Its the Encoding Class:

```
        var binary = GetBinaryFileFromDatabase();

        var inputLines = Encoding.Default.GetString(binary).Split('\n');
        var outputLines = new List<string>();

        foreach (var line in inputLines)
        {
            var columns = line.Split(';');
            if (columns.Length > 28 && columns[28] != null && columns[28].Length > 0)
            {
                columns[28] = columns[28].Replace(Path.GetFileName(columns[28]), "SomeValue");
            }
            outputLines.Add(string.Join(";", columns));
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, outputLines);
```

Thanks everybody!